# Running SQL-like queries on .net assembly metadata

Tags: sql, .net, reflection, metadata, .net-assembly

I know the metadata of .net assemblies is stored in a tabular way, as described in ECMA-335. Has anyone developed a way to query this data using an SQL like language (or any query language!)?

The reason I want to do this is do ask questions about a code base such as:

1. Give me the names of the classes and fieldnames where the type T occurs as a field.
2. Give me the number of classes which have at least one field with a valuetype and at least one field with a reference type.
3. Give me the number of occurences of this type as a field.

One solution might be to read the tables off the assembly, and load them into a SQL database, but this seems like a lot of work, if no one has done this before.

Comment: LINQ works quite well for that I think. Collecting the relevant metadata is not that hard: Get all Assemblies, Get all Types, Get all Members. From there you can query pretty much everything using LINQ.

Comment: yeah actually, that's a good point. I think i was overcomplicating this in my head! Put that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LINQ` works quite well for that I think. Collecting the relevant metadata is not that hard: Get all Assemblies, Get all Types, Get all Members. From there you can query pretty much everything using `LINQ`.

Have a look at this example:

```cs
var members = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
    .SelectMany(x => x.GetMembers())
    .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(members.Count(x => x.MemberType == MemberTypes.Method));
```